# Sort woocommerce products by featured

Tags: sorting, woocommerce

I'd like to sort woocommerce products by "featured", how do I achieve this? I have a code that works but showing only featured products when my expectation is featured products first then the rest of the products. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'hugo_boss_catalog_orderby' );
function hugo_boss_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $orderby['featured'] = __('Featured', 'woocommerce');

    return $orderby;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'obama_trump_product_query' );
function obama_trump_product_query( $q ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['orderby']) && 'featured' === esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) ) {
        $tax_query = $q->get('tax_query');
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); // Or "ASC"
    }
}
```

It works but showing strictly the featured products while my expectation is "featured products first then the rest of the products.